# Excel VBA Reference Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell in vba that tells me the count of rows. I want to use that row to select all the information.

I want to select cell range J2:S150 .

My code is below:

```
Dim I As String

I = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value

Range("J2: S + I").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

I keep geting a syntex error. Again the Value I is based on a count in my spread sheet. I want it to select cell range J2:150.

Thanks

Comment: you're closing the double quote too late in your address string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that to

```
Range("J2:S" + I).Select
```

and to simplify it all, change your code to:

```
Range("J2: S" & Sheet1.[A2]).Copy
Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Maybe `Sheet2.Range("A1") = Range("J2: S" & Sheet1.[A2]).Value` ?

Comment: use "&" as concatenation operator : `Range("J2:S" & I).Select`